# PRP, PRF and modular arithmetic

Tags: pseudo-random-function, modular-arithmetic, pseudo-random-permutation

Are there any arithmetic or mathematical functions that can be used as PRPs or PRFs ?  Since, Conventional block ciphers like AES are that are proven to be good PRPs are not based on mathematics but on other principles like confusion and diffusion etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to give a precise definition of what you mean by an "arithmetic function". Is AES an "arithmetic function"?  How about cubing modulo a RSA modulus?  Also, please elaborate on what you mean by "simulate".  Finally, I suggest you add some context and motivation: why are you asking? what is the real goal? what research have you done to try to solve this on your own?

Comment: AES does not simulate a PRP, and a PRF ? I'm looking for functions based on hard mathematical problems, like factoring, or DH... Maybe the term "simulates" is not OK... ?

Comment: Do you want DDH/RSA-based PRFs? If so, we have them and I will answer.

Comment: @xagawa Yes, I want that :-)

Comment: Are you asking for an arithmetic function $(k,x)\mapsto F(k,x)$ such that, for some random unknown $k$, $x\mapsto F(k,x)$ would be computationally indistinguishable from a random permutation or function? That seems to be a good question with some useful characterization of _arithmetic_, which is missing. Ultimately, AES or SHA-1 can be written as a long composition of arithmetic functions, if you consider $(a,b)\mapsto a\bmod b$ to be arithmetic. Any interesting definitions of _arithmetic_ that I can think of uses a threshold; like, at most some number of operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do you want DDH/RSA-based PRFs? If so, we have them and I will answer. –  xagawa
>
> @xagawa Yes, I want that :-) –  Dingo13

I list the PRFs based on the number-theoretical assumptions.
They are ``arithmetic or mathematical function.''
You can use the Feistel network to obtain (S)PRPs from PRFs in theory.

## From the DDH assumption

The [Naor-Reingold Pseudorandom Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naor-Reingold_Pseudorandom_Function) is a PRF based on the DDH assumption.
Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a finite group of order prime $q$ with a generator $g$,
on which the DDH problem is hard.
Let $\{0,1\}^\ell$ be a domain.
The function is defined as
$$\mathrm{PRF_{NR}}(k, x) = g^{a_0 \prod_{i=1}^{\ell} a_i^{x_i}},$$
where $k = (a_0,a_1\dots,a_{\ell}) \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{\ell}$.
For the proof, see [the original article](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=972643) in J. ACM.

Lewko and Waters generalized the NR PRFs in CCS 2009 (and [ePrint 2009/486](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/486)).
Their PRFs are based on the decisional linear assumption (and its weaker variants).

### Most efficient one

Under stronger assumptions such as the DHI assumption,
 we have a cute PRF, say,
[the Dodis-Yampolskiy PRF](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-30580-4_28) proposed as
[Verifiable Random Function (VRF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_random_function).

Let $\{0,1\}^{\ell}$ be the domain of PRF.
Suppose that $2^{\ell}$ is a polynoimal of the security parameter. 
The DY PRF is defined on a symmetric bilinear group as follows:
$$\mathrm{PRF}_{DY}(k,x) = e(g,g)^{1/(x+k)},$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}_q$.

## From the factoring assumption

This is a classical result obtained by a combining the Blum-Blum-Shub PRG and the Goldreich-Goldwasser-Micali PRF from any PRG.
[Naor, Reingold, and Rosen](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539701389257) improved efficiency of factoring-based PRFs.
See the original article available at [ECCC TR 2001-064](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2001/064/),

## From the hardness of lattice problems

Nowadays, the lattice problems are often employed to construct cryptogrphic primitives.
You can find the PRFs from lattices in
[Banerjee, Peikert, and Rosen (EUROCRYPT 2012)](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-29011-4_42),
[Alwen, Krenn, Pietrzak, and Wichs (CRYPTO 2013)](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-40041-4_4),
and [Banerjee and Peikert (ePrint 2014/074)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/074).

Comment: I do not understand " $2^{\ell}$ _is a polynoimal of the security parameter_", and that has nothing to do with the minor typo. The answer is still great.

Comment: Correctly speaking, the size of domain $2^{\ell}$ should be small, because the construction is based on $2^{\ell}$-DBDHI assumption.

Comment: A note: the results in the Alwen et al paper are actually not strong enough to yield PRFs (contrary to what the paper says), because they are limited to an a priori bounded polynomial number of samples.

Answer (score -3):

No. Conceptually , not so strongly close but similar ones that would come closer is $k$-wise Independent Distributions/Functions .

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because I don't think it has sufficient explanation or depth

Comment: I've upvoted it because I think it is correct and points the original poster to the key technical term, from which they can find more.  You can look up what $k$-wise independent hash functions are pretty easily; I expect they're probably in Wikipedia and in good textbooks on derandomization/randomized algorithms.

Comment: Possibly. Even just the addition of a relevant link would I think satisfy my worries

Comment: I believe , what could be found out from google , can be left for seekers exercise and save some time of one who answers it.